zero-inflation analysis multilevel for continuos data (not count data)
I was trying to fit a multilevel model, but I discovered that my dependent variable is highly skewed and zero-inflated. Individuals report 5 times a day for 7 days their level of paranoia and the perception of the other as dominant in interpersonal exchanges. We also collected pathological traits in the data (es. BPD). In 2000 observations, individuals rated their paranoia "zero" 1500 times.
I tried to run a model taking into account the nature of the data
Eg.
# gamma model
model.1a <- "StatePara1 ~ day + STPD.c + (1 + day|mail)"
fit.1a <- glmer(
  model.1a,
  data = merged_data_sb,
  family = Gamma(link = "inverse"),
  control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 2e5)))

or also
Eg.
# mixed logit model
zero_model <- glmer(
  StatePara == 0 ~ 1 + BPD.c + day + (1+day|mail),
  data = merged_data_sb,
  family = binomial
)

# Filter data for non-zero values

non_zero_data <- merged_data_sb[merged_data_sb$StatePara > 0, ]

# Second part: Mixed range model for non-zero values

gamma_model <- glmmTMB(
  StatePara ~ 1 + BPD.c + day + (1 + day|mail),
  data = non_zero_data,
  family = Gamma(link = "log")
)

# Combine the two models into a two-part model

two_part_model <- list(
  zero_model = zero_model,
  gamma_model = gamma_model
)

The models are not working properly (they run, but every model is not significant, which is very unlikely since BPD and other pathological traits have paranoia as a core symptom)
How can I manage this data?
Among 6 pathological traits, we did not find any effect, which is weird considering that there is an association with paranoia usually
